# How do i store Private and Public keys in Google Cloud

Tags: google, google-cloud-platform

So, we have our own Internal CA which needs to the signing for internal app. So, do I store the Root CA's private and public key in Google Secrets?

These keys will need to be accessed to sign CSR, which whenever needed will be generated by a different app.

Comment: Whether or not to use a specific product is off topic here.  Google Secrets might be perfectly reasonable today, but due to some newly discovered bug, vulnerability, or policy, could be completely unreasonable tomorrow.  The best advice is: Use some sort of secure storage. We can't offer product recommendations, 'cause the world of infosec changes daily.

Comment: You can check Google Cloud Key Vault Service, which uses Hardware modules for storage of keys, at least as per the details they have shared on their website.

Comment: The root signing keys should be stored on a machine that is not connected to anything and locked away in a secure location. You should not be signing anything with the root keys except for intermediate signing certificates. Since you mentioned Google Cloud, review the Google Cloud Certificate Authority Service. https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments it is not advisable to store Root CA’s private and public key in Google Secrets.

These root keys should be stored on a machine that is not connected to anything and should be locked away in a secure location. You should not be signing anything with the root keys except for intermediate signing certificates. Since it is mentioned in the question about Google Cloud, you can refer to the [Google Cloud Certificate Authority Service](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service).